# Calling conn.query in a loop causes: Variable 'conn' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, mariadb

I have a route like below in which I want to get all posts (like in twitter) from the db. I have separated the likes and images for each post in its own sql table called "post_likes" & "post_images".

After retrieving the posts I want to add the likes for each post and then send it back to the client.

But looping through an array and calling `conn.query` each time gives me these two errors:

`error TS7034: Variable 'conn' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.`

`error TS7005: Variable 'conn' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Why can't typescript determine the type of conn in a map or forEach loop?

```
router.get("/get/:token", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  /**
   * Gets all Post from you and your friends
   */

  ... 

  let conn;  // ERROR <-- Variable 'conn' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.
  
  try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();

    ... 

    /* get all posts */
    const queryGetPostsResult = await conn.query(queryGetPosts);
    const getPosts: Array<Post> = [...queryGetPostsResult];

    /* add images and likes to each post */
    let clientPosts: Array<ClientPost> = await Promise.all(getPosts.map(async (post: Post) => {

      /* FIXME get the likes */
      const queryGetLikes: string = `SELECT user_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=?`

      const queryGetLikesResult = await conn.query(queryGetLikes, [post.id]); // ERROR <-- Variable 'conn' implicitly has an 'any' type.

      const likes: Array<number> = queryGetLikesResult.map((x: { user_id: number }) => x.user_id);

      /* TODO get the images */
      const images: Array<string> = [];


      const clientPost: ClientPost = {
        id: post.id,
        writtenBy: post.written_by,
        content: post.content,
        writtenAt: post.written_at,
        images,
        likes,
      };

      return clientPost;
    }));

    return res.send(clientPosts);
  } catch(err: unknown) {
    throw console.log(colors.red(`/api/post/get/:token => ${err}`));
  } finally {
    if (conn) return conn.release();
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't have any type annotation on `conn`, so (as the error says), it defaults to the `any` type. Look at the type that `getConnection` returns, and put a type annotation on `conn` to indicate what type it has. (Hopefully you're using `strictNullChecks`. If so, you'll need to include `| undefined` in the type because you don't initially set it to anything. Example: `let conn: ConnectionClassName | undefined;`.)

Comment: But if I don't map through the array I won't get the error at all. I will try your suggestion and will update you, but to me it seems like the problem is not the missing type annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like T.J. Crowder suggested the problem was the missing type annotation at `let conn;` but I still don't understand why typescript only throws an error when I try to call `conn.query()` inside a loop. If someone knows please explain this to me.

I also had to add `if (!conn) throw "conn is undefined"` to break out of the try & map block.

So I've edited the route to the following:

```
router.get("/get/:token", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  /**
   * Gets all Post from you and your friends
   */

  ... 

  let conn: PoolConnection | undefined;  // <-- ADDED TO FIX THE ERROR!!!
  
  try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    if (!conn) throw "conn is unknown"; // <-- ADDED TO FIX THE ERROR!!!

    ... 

    /* get all posts */
    const queryGetPostsResult = await conn.query(queryGetPosts);
    const getPosts: Array<Post> = [...queryGetPostsResult];

    /* add images and likes to each post */
    let clientPosts: Array<ClientPost> = await Promise.all(getPosts.map(async (post: Post) => {

      if (!conn) throw "conn is unknown"; // <-- ADDED TO FIX THE ERROR!!!

      /* FIXME get the likes */
      const queryGetLikes: string = `SELECT user_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=?`

      const queryGetLikesResult = await conn.query(queryGetLikes, [post.id]);

      const likes: Array<number> = queryGetLikesResult.map((x: { user_id: number }) => x.user_id);

      /* TODO get the images */
      const images: Array<string> = [];


      const clientPost: ClientPost = {
        id: post.id,
        writtenBy: post.written_by,
        content: post.content,
        writtenAt: post.written_at,
        images,
        likes,
      };

      return clientPost;
    }));

    return res.send(clientPosts);
  } catch(err: unknown) {
    throw console.log(colors.red(`/api/post/get/:token => ${err}`));
  } finally {
    if (conn) return conn.release();
  }
});
```